# How to fix Plugin Dependency error in Java

Tags: java, maven

I am new to java
I am getting this error when maven compile Java code

> [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
>   'build.plugins.plugin[org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin].dependencies.dependency.version'
>   for gov.nih.nlm.nls.lvg:lvgdist:jar is missing. @ line 174, column 20

I checked this library it exists

[image]

I checked the pom.xml for this subproject

looks ok to me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more contributor 
    license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for additional 
    information regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file to 
    you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use 
    this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of 
    the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required 
    by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the 
    License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
    OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific 
    language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>ctakes-clinical-pipeline</artifactId>
    <name>Apache cTAKES ctakes-clinical-pipeline</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
        <artifactId>ctakes</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </parent>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-utils</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-context-tokenizer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-preprocessor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-lvg</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-chunker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-ne-contexts</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-pos-tagger</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-drug-ner</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-assertion</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-dependency-parser</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-ytex</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-ytex-res</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-ytex-uima</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-dictionary-lookup-fast</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-constituency-parser</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-coreference</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ctakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>ctakes-clinical-pipeline-res</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>runCPE</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>runCPE</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <!-- depends on other modules being on classpath -->
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>java</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                            <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>                     
                            <mainClass>org.apache.uima.tools.cpm.CpmFrame</mainClass>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument />
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>gov.nih.nlm.nls.lvg</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lvgdist</artifactId>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>                     
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>runCVD</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>runCVD</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <!-- depends on other modules being on classpath -->
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>java</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                            <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>

                            <mainClass>org.apache.uima.tools.cvd.CVD</mainClass>
                            <!-- Have to specify at least one parameter otherwise, CVD thinks 
                                it's an invalid param because MVN passes null when joining to the mvn thread -->
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-lookandfeel</argument>
                                <argument>javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>gov.nih.nlm.nls.lvg</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lvgdist</artifactId>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Except it doesn't have `<version>...</version>` that the error message is helpfully telling you.

Comment: that was the problem, thanks :) plz put it as an answer so i mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Strelok mentioned

the are missing ... tag

it worked after adding this tag